# Does MPLAB X have a call-graph analysis tool?

Tags: pic, c, mplabx, stack

I'd like to start understanding how deep my microcontroller's stack goes (even if it's only an estimation).

How can I do this using MPLAB X?

Answer (score 3):

- During code editing, you have the possibility to view the [call
  graph](http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:call-graph):

[image: call graph]

Video: [MPLAB X TV Call Graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTrQ6Fg2gHQ)

- During debugging, you have the possibility to view the [call
  stack](http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:call-stack):

> The call stack window provides a way to view the subroutine calls and
>   interrupts that have occurred to bring the program to its current
>   position.
>
> To view the call stack, select from the main menu: Window ▸ Debugging
>   ▸ Call Stack or use the keyboard shortcut Alt+Shift+3.